# Calculating probability given 3 or more gaussian

Tags: python, probability

In the most simple case, I would like to calculate P(X

In my actual case,  I would like to calculate P (X < Y and X < Z) given that X, Y,Z are drawn from gaussian distributions with different means and different sigmas.

At its core this stack exchange is describing my problem well:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262046/probability-of-gaussian-being-smaller-than-multiple-other-gaussians

I am having trouble translating it into python code.  And extending it into the N case with N > 2.

I am also happy if scipy, statsmodel has some pre-calcs either in full or in parts...but I have not been able to find anything.

ideally it would allow:

```py
    def calculate_prob(*list_of_mu_sigma):
       # Takes in a list of mu/sigmas (gaussians) of form:
         [[1, 5], [16, 3] ...] of N length  
         # do magic
         Return:  probability of 1st element in list winning
```

Comment: Is it always the case that there is one variable which all expressions have in common, and otherwise the variables are all different? E.g. A > Z, B > Z, C > Z, all have Z in common, and A, B, C are all different.

Comment: there is no common distribution Z and all A, B, C is different.  We could make a common distribution Z to compare A B C to, but this Z would need to be specially designed to be useful  (otherwise let Z have mean >>> other means, and sigma <<< small, then A to Z says A larger 100% of time...)